# cygwin bash not returning a valid result

Tags: bash, gcc, netbeans, terminal, cygwin

I am following this :

Step 2: Installing Cygwin

1. Cygwin can be downloaded from http://www.cygwin.com
2. Run the setup file.
3. Install from internet. Specify C:\cygwin as the root directory.
4. In the Select Packages dialog box, select the packages required. gcc-core, gcc-g++, gdb, and make packages are most important. These are the C core, C++ core, the GNU Debugger and the GNU version of ‘make’ utility. These packages will be under the ‘Devel’ category.
5. Complete the installation.

Step 3: Testing Cygwin

To test whether Cygwin was installed properly, try the following by opening the bash shell:

1. cygcheck -c cygwin
2. gcc --version
3. g++ --version
4. make --version
5. gdb --version

If the version details are displayed for all these commands, the installation of Cygwin has been successful.

I got this from [here](http://blog.karthiksankar.com/configuring-cygwin-with-netbeans-in-windows/)

But the result I get is:

[image]

What is wrong or missing with my installation.

Follow up question:

I wanted to use the terminal window in netbeans that is why I installed this.
In this terminal widnow I also have problem. I cant type anything on it. Is this the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **/usr/bin/g++**. If it is not found, then you don't have g++ installed (installation may have had problems).

You can follow the same procedure for the rest of your commands

If **/usr/bin/g++** runs successfully, it means you don't have **/usr/bin** in your PATH (which is very unlikely). You can put that in your PATH in your startup file.

Comment: when i try to search it `/usr/bin/g++` i cant find it maybe there was error i think i have to reinstall it again

Comment: You are right. Also check **/bin/ls -lrtd /usr/bin/* | less**. Usually there will be couple of hundred executable even on a bare-bones cygwin installation. You should be able to find all your commands there. If you rerun cygwin setup.exe, by default, it will try to refresh all your packages. Let me know if that doesn't work. I have faced a lot of strange problems in cygwin which disappeared with a refresh.